# Detect when map 'reclusters' features

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I need to run some code when the map *"reclusters"*, see this [GIF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uV2x9l6o_bs1z1AcskRE3eQLUQxJ2Zjl/view) to see what i mean.

Is there a way know when this happens, or some sort of **event** to listen for?

Something like:

```
map.on('cluster', function() {
   //code here
})
```

My current solution is to run my code on:

```
map.on('zoom', () => {
    //my code
})
```

By running my code on the `zoom` event, my code runs every time the user zooms in or zooms out, though I just need it to run when the map is clustering. Is there something that can be done here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to find a solution, probably not the best, but the following code is working for me: *(simplified)*

```
// to keep track of the amount of clusters rendered
var previousClusterCount = 0

function foo() {
  //get all currently rendered clusters
  clusters = map.querySourceFeatures('your-cluster-layer')

  // if the amount of rendered clusters is different from the previous cluster count
  // then it means that the user has zoomed enough to trigger a "reclustering"
  // as shown in the GIF above
  if (clusters.length !== previousClusterCount) {
    //update cluster count
    previousClusterCount = clusters.length
    //run some code
  }
}

// set callback on zoom
map.on('zoom', foo)
```